# Shell script for insert multiple records into a Database

Tags: shell, unix, informix

I have a table in an Informix DB into which I want to insert multiple records at a time.
Data for one of the column should be unique & other column data may be the same for all the records I insert

Typical Insert Statement I use to insert one row :

insert into employee(empid, country, state) values(1, us, ca)

Now I want to pass different values for the 'empid' column, & data in rest of the columns can remain the same.

I am looking for something like looping empid & prompting user to enter the Start & End  range of values for empid
When User enters Start Value as 1 & End Value as 100, the script should inset 100 records with empid's from 1 to 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please notice that you need to pass the start and end parameters as input arguments to your script:

```
#!/bin/sh

start=$1
end=$2

while [[ $start -le $end ]];
do
  echo "insert into employee(empid, country, state) values(${start}, us, ca)"
  start=`expr $start + 1`
done
```

Comment: I tried this but on executing the script I saw an error at the line  start='expr $ start + 1'

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses a stored procedure to wrap the insert statement in a loop. Probably more suitable for a large amount of data where performance is critical:

File InsertEmployee.sql

```
drop procedure InsertEmployee;

create procedure InsertEmployee(
        p_start_empid   like employee.empid,
        p_end_empid     like employee.empid,
        p_country       like employee.country,
        p_state         like employee.state
) returning char(255);

        define i integer;

        let i = p_start_empid;

        while i <= p_end_empid
                insert into employee (
                        empid,
                        country,
                        state
                ) values (
                        i,
                        p_country,
                        p_state
                );

                -- logging
                -- if (DBINFO('sqlca.sqlerrd2') > 0) then
                --      return "inserted empid=" || i || " country=" || p_country || " state=" || p_state with resume;
                -- end if

                let i = i + 1;
        end while;
end procedure;
```

Load stored procedure into your database:

```
dbaccess mydatabasename InsertEmployee.sql
```

Call the stored procedure from the shell prompt:

```
echo 'execute procedure InsertEmployee(1,100,"us","ca");' | dbaccess mydatabasename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a namesArray=("name1","name2","name3")

inserts=""

for i in "{arr[@]}"
do
    inserts+="INSERT INTO persons(id, name) VALUES (0,'$i');"
done

echo $inserts | dbaccess yourDataBase
```

That will insert 3 rows (i asume that your primary key is serial number, thats why is 0 in values field). In informix you cannot add multiple rows in the same insert, thats why i create an insert per row.

Informix: INSERT INTO table VALUES(0);
mySQL & SQL Server: INSERT INTO table VALUES(0),(1),(2); <- 3 rows